# Hoe to choose a spline for expression data (mRNA and proteins)

Tags: r, regression, splines, bioinformatics

I'm using [timeOmics](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/timeOmics.html) to model a time series of expression data on mRNA and proteins data. The amount of samples is rather small (7 groups, 2-7 samples per group) but the features space is rather large (8k in mRNA, 3k in proteins).

TimeOmics uses the lmms::lmmSpline algorithm for spline modeling and gives a option to choose between "cubic", "p-spline" or "cubic p-spline". I could not find any hard evidence on which splince would be best for my data and when I compared them, I just find that cubic p-splines receives more features as noise compare with the other models.

Would someone advise me on which spline would be best or recommend a paper where I could find that information?

Also, I am not sure if I should set the knots as the number of samples or leave it for the algorithm to decide.

Comment: [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/558759/28500) provides a brief summary of different types of smooths and splines.

Comment: How many distinct time points do you have? It's not clear from the question whether the "2-7 samples per group" represent 2-7 time points per group or 2-7 samples per group each evaluated at several time points. Please edit the question to clarify that, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.